# How to make a form self referencing in Drupal? Or any other options?

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I would like to make a form I have in my website self referencing. Or if that's not an option, how would I go for, for example, showing the results of a search I make in my site?

I have a site in which you search for places and it returns a list of places for your preferences. At the moment my script creates a new node every time a user searches but this isn't convenient anymore. How do I change it so that the page content is changed and I see the results instead of the search form?

Thanks,

Comment: As I understand, you want to have a page (let's say it's 'search-places') where you want to render a search form. After submitting this form you want to stay in the same page but instead of displaying a form you want to display search result? Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, except the form is presented on the front page (www.example.com) and the results I would like them to be presented on www.example.com/search/results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect your form to a page passing a query string with the string of what the user searched and then use $_GET['search_param'] in your search/restuls page to handle what will be displayed to the user.

```
function yourform_form($form_state) {
    $form = array();
    //$form['your_search_field']
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourform_form_submit';
    return $form;
}

function yourform_form_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
    $query = 'search_param='. $form_state['values']['your_search_field'];
    drupal_goto('search/results', query);
}
```

If you're using Drupal 7 your submit function should look like:

```
 function yourform_form_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
        $options['query']['search_param'] = $form_state['values']['your_search_field'];
        drupal_goto('search/results', $options);
    }
```

After you submit you should be redirected to http://yoursite.com/search/results?search_param=my_search_value

Note that this technique is used by popular search engines:

https://www.google.com/search?q=my_search_value

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried to do what you said but unfortunately I get an error: `"Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_http_build_query() must be an array, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/includes/common.inc on line 2161 and defined in drupal_http_build_query() (line 472 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/includes/common.inc)."`

Comment: The user checks an bunch of checkboxes and then submits his query. What I do is I get the values into an array:

`$checked = array_filter($form_state['values']['options']);
 $res = implode(',', $checked);`

Then I follow your instructions:

`$a['query'] = 'search=' . $res;
 drupal_goto('search/results', $a);`

But I arrive at that error I just posted above.

Comment: Try: $a['query']['search'] = $res; - I presume that the output of $res is correctly returning a string with comma separated values

Comment: Great! Just edited the answer itself with this correction for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should include `$form['#action']` to lead you to specific page after submit:

```
function example_form($form_state) {
    $form = array();
    //your form code
    //...
    $form['#action'] = url('search/results');
    return $form;
}
```

On submitting form (`example_form_submit`) you should take all your values and save them to cookies using `user_cookie_save` function and on your page you can use this cookies. 
You also could `serialize` your values to deal only with one cookie if you want, and then `unserialize` them on your page. You can delete cookie using `user_cookie_delete` function.

You should define path `search/results` where you could take those cookies data and manipulate with it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. How do I make the POST data and manipulate it? Imagine I wanted to print out a simple <div> with some data in it. How would I go about that?